# How do I add DISQUS comment count in Views' sort criteria?

Tags: views, comments

I am using DISQUS comments platform in my Drupal 7 site. My goal is to show the 10 most commented posts using views. For this I need to add 'DISQUS comment count' in 'SORT CRITERIA'. How do I do this.

The field 'DISQUS comment count' is not listed in 'Add sort criteria'.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but DISQUS comment count is not in your database, it's retrieved from DISQUS server each time. Or this was the way I used it last time, so maybe my memory is wrong or it was changed?

Comment: 'Disqus comment count' is listed in 'Add fields'. Is there a way to make this field listed in 'Add sort criteria'?

Comment: Fields that are not stored in db can easily be displayed, but cannot really be used to sort, so so far it is consistent with what I remember. **If** I'm right, then no, there is no easy way, and you should post a feature request in the issue queue of a module you are using.